# One to Many and Many to one mapping shows null in database column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am writing a web application where I am getting a JSON object from client of format:

```
var applicationForm = {
            projectTitle: "",
            applicantRow: [{
                nameApplicant: "",
                emailApplicant: "",
                departmentApplicant: ""
            }],
            experimentRow: [{
                lightOn: "",
                tempDay: "",
                ....
            }],
            startdate: "",
            enddate: ""
            ....
    }
```

Now i want to store this in 3 tables namely Application, applicant, experimentalconditions, where applicationId will act as foreign key in applicant and experimentalconditions table.

```
@Entity
public class Application {
   private long application_id;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   public long getApplication_id() {
       return application_id;
   }
   ...
   private List<ExperimentalConditions> experimentRow;
   @OneToMany(targetEntity=ExperimentalConditions.class,mappedBy="application",
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
   public List<ExperimentalConditions> getExperimentRow() {
       return experimentRow;
   }
...
```

ExperminetalCondition class:

```
@Entity
public class ExperimentalConditions {
    private long experimental_id;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long getExperimental_id() {
        return experimental_id;
    }
    ...(getter,setters for other variables)

    private Application application;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationid")
    public Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }
    ...(getter setters)
```

Same setup with applicant table
In my applicationDAO class i am saving this application object in table, which should then itself save it in 3 different tables.

ApplicationDAO :

```
 public void save(Application applicationData){
     getSession().save(applicationData);
 }
```

This is my controller class where i am calling this save method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/submitApp",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public Application sumitApp(@RequestBody Application app ){
    try{
        applicationDAO.save(app);
    }
```

This save data for for applicationForm in all 3 tables, but application_id(foreign key) shows null in applicant and experimentalconditions table. Thus if i want to get back data, i can't retrieve it. Please tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: By seeing the json i feel that your design is worng. The Application class should contains the other two classes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that why my design is wrong? I didn't quite get you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your relationship owner configuraiton you need to get ExperimentalConditions object from your json string and write this line before you save your main application data

```
applicationData.getExperimentRow().setApplicaiton(applicationData);
```

Repeat same thing for your other relational table (applicant) also